# Solve for $x$ where $A = \sin (x) /B + \cos (x)/C$ where $A, B,$ and $C$ are known

Tags: trigonometry

It's been a few years since I've done trig and I've reduced an equation down to the following:

$$A = \sin (x)/B + \cos (x)/C$$

Is it possible to solve for $x?$

**Edit:** Diagram and clarification added.

The problem I'm trying to solve is the angle of rotation for a scaled down rectangle inside another rectangle such that all 4 corners touch the original rectangle.

[image: Diagram of the Math]

PS: Thank you all for the amazing responses!  This was clearly way above my head.  I'm super jealous and wish I had continued to pursue math after graduation.  I'll definitely have to start brushing up...

Answer (score 2):

This is a linear equation in sine and cosine. Rewrite it as
$$
C\sin x+B\cos x=ABC
$$
and then divide both sides by $\sqrt{B^2+C^2}$:
$$
\frac{C}{\sqrt{B^2+C^2}}\sin x+\frac{B}{\sqrt{B^2+C^2}}\cos x=\frac{ABC}{\sqrt{B^2+C^2}}
$$
Set $s=ABC/\sqrt{B^2+C^2}$ and find an angle $\alpha$ such that
$$
\sin\alpha=\frac{C}{\sqrt{B^2+C^2}},
\qquad
\cos\alpha=\frac{B}{\sqrt{B^2+C^2}}
$$
which is surely possible. Then the equation becomes
$$
\cos x\cos\alpha+\sin x\sin\alpha=s
$$
or
$$
\cos(x-\alpha)=s
$$
that is elementary.

Of course, there's no solution if $|s|>1$.

Note about “surely possible”: the point with coordinates
$$
\left(\frac{B}{\sqrt{B^2+C^2}},\frac{C}{\sqrt{B^2+C^2}}\right)
$$
lies on the unit circle. Connecting it with the origin defines the required angle $\alpha$, considering as the other angle side the positive $x$-semiaxis.

Comment: As a side note, it is "surely possible" to find such an $\alpha$ because we have
$$
\left(\frac{B}{\sqrt{B^2 + C^2}}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{C}{\sqrt{B^2 + C^2}}\right)^2 = 1
$$
and when we have two numbers satisfying this pythagorean property with hypotenuse equal to $1$, there is always an angle such that the sine of that angle is one of the numbers, and the cosine of that angle is the other one.

Comment: @Arthur Yes, the two numbers are the coordinates of a point on the unit circle.

Comment: I added my original diagram for clarity.  So if |$s|$ cannot be greater than 1, I'm a little confused.  Assume the outer rectangle has a height of 100 and width of 120 and the inner rectangle is scaled down by 0.9 (height 90, width 108).  Given your equation, $s$ = 6913.99.  That's clearly > 1?!?

Comment: @MCTaylor17 Assuming your equation is correct, the case $s>1$ means your problem has no solution.

Answer (score 0):

assuming $bc \neq 0,$ we will try to solve. we can rewrite your equation in the form $$\dfrac{abc}{b^2 + c^2} =  \dfrac{c}{\sqrt{b^2+c^2}} \sin x + \dfrac{b}{\sqrt{b^2+c^2}}\cos x = \cos(x - t)$$ where $t$ is defined by 
$ \cos t = \dfrac{b}{\sqrt{b^2 + c^2}}, \sin t = \dfrac{c}{\sqrt{b^2+c^2}}$

the equation has solution provided $$|abc| < \sqrt{b^2 + c^2}. $$

the solution is $$x = t \pm \cos^{-1}\left( \frac{abc}{\sqrt{b^2+c^2}}\right)+2k\pi $$ with $k$ an arbitrary integer.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is in terms of complex numbers:
$$
A = \frac{\sin (x) }{B} + \frac{\cos (x)}{C}
\\
A = \frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix} }{2iB} + \frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2C}
$$
which can be written as a quadratic equation for $e^{ix}$.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way to solve the equation could be to use tangent half-angle substitution (Weierstrass substitution). Let $t=\tan(\frac x2)$ and assuming $b\neq0 $ and $c\neq0 $, the equation reduces to $$b(a  c+1)t^2 -2 c t+(a c-1)b=0$$ the solution of which being $$t_{\pm}=\frac{c\pm\sqrt{b^2+c^2-a^2 b^2 c^2}}{b (a c+1)}$$ which are real only if $$a^2 \le \frac{1}{b^2}+ \frac{1}{c^2}$$

Answer (score -1):

$$
\cos(x - \phi) = \cos x\cos\phi + \sin x\sin \phi
$$
let
$$
\frac{1}{B} = \sin \phi\\
\frac{1}{C} = \cos \phi\\
$$
where $\vert\frac{1}{B}\vert \leq 1 $ and similarly for $\vert\frac{1}{C}\vert \leq 1 $.
thus
$$
\tan\phi = \frac{C}{B}
$$
provided that $C/B$ such that $|\tan \phi| <\infty$ 
then we have
$$
\cos(x-\phi) = A \text{for $\vert A\vert < 1$}
$$
solve for $x$ as usual.

Comment: @Arthur fair point I will modify the post.

Comment: If $\frac{1}{B} = 0.1$ and $\frac{1}{C} = 0.1$, what should $\phi$ be?

Comment: @Arthur as we speak I am handing back my phd! ;).

Comment: did you have enough rest?

Comment: @abel midnight here in the uk, and after a days work..so probably not. But no excuses, this problem is doable by most people on here in their sleep!

Comment: we all make this kind of mistakes. don't be too hard on yourself. as fellow differential equation enthusiast, i like  company.